# Bind9 dynamic zone updates are denied by apparmor in Debian11

Tags: bind, apparmor

I installed bind9 with chroot on Debian11, described by this tutorial: https://wiki.debian.org/Bind9#Debian_Jessie_and_later

It works fine, but as soon as I turn on dynamic zone updates, it will fail with this reason in the syslog:

```
Jul 18 19:22:52 NS kernel: [12161.968582] audit: type=1400 audit(1658164972.109:107): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="named" name="/var/bind9/chroot/" pid=18104 comm="named" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=106 ouid=0
```

I thought it might be some missing option from `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.named` so I added `/var/bind9/chroot` to it, now the file looks like this:

```
/var/bind9/chroot/** r,
/var/bind9/chroot/etc/bind/** r,
/var/bind9/chroot/usr/** rw,
/var/bind9/chroot/var/** rw,
/var/bind9/chroot/dev/** rw,
/var/bind9/chroot/run/** rw,
```

Then I restarted `apparmor` and also `named` services, but the problem is the same. If I look into with `apparmor_status` command, it brings the right named process id, so there is no another false process running or so. Expect this, the chrooted `named` works fine. If I turn off enforcing from this profile or I disable `apparmor` completely, then the dynamic updates are also work, but I would like to fix this somehow.

**UPDATE:**

If I modify `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.named` to this:

```
/var/bind9/chroot/** r,
/var/bind9/chroot/etc/bind/** rw,
/var/bind9/chroot/usr/** rw,
/var/bind9/chroot/var/** rw,
/var/bind9/chroot/dev/** rw,
/var/bind9/chroot/run/** rw,
```

then the dynamic zone updates are working. But still get that error messages I noticed before and getting that exactly when a dynamic zone update is triggered. It is a bit annoying why I get that messages.

Comment: similar Q/A on SF: https://serverfault.com/questions/412012/ubuntu-bind9-apparmor-read-permission-denied-chroot-jail

Comment: @A.B I read that already, but the solution posted there doesn't solve my problem. Still getting the error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The log message (wrapped for readability)

```
Jul 18 19:22:52 NS kernel: [12161.968582] audit: type=1400 audit(1658164972.109:107): \
    apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="named" name="/var/bind9/chroot/" pid=18104 \
    comm="named" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=106 ouid=0
```

indicates the `named` process was trying to read the directory `/var/bind9/chroot` and was denied.

The rule examples in `man 5 apparmor.d` say (emphasis mine):

> When AppArmor looks up a directory the pathname being looked up will
> end with a slash (e.g., `/var/tmp/`); otherwise it will not end with a
> slash. Only rules that match a trailing slash will match directories.
> Some examples, **none matching the `/tmp/` directory itself**, are:
>
> ```
>   /tmp/*
>       Files directly in /tmp.
>
>   /tmp/*/
>       Directories directly in /tmp.
>
>   /tmp/**
>       Files and directories anywhere underneath /tmp.
>
>   /tmp/**/
>       Directories anywhere underneath /tmp.
> ```

In other words, your first rule

```
/var/bind9/chroot/** r,
```

only allows *reading files* within the `/var/bind9/chroot/` directory, but *reading the directory listing* is not allowed. And that is apparently what `named` wants to do.

To fix it, you would need to add a line:

```
/var/bind9/chroot/ r,
```

because `**` won't match an empty string.